# How can I call React hooks inside a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object as a state with some properties. I want to update the state in a condition with a hook.
But it causes an infinite loop.

Can I update the state directly like this?

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({name: '' })

if (info.name === '') {
     info.name = 'empty'
 }
```

Is this ok to do?

Comment: No you don't ever change state directly. Show the other updating code that's causing an infinite loop

Comment: You can update the state (properly, using setState) as long as it's not one of the triggers for that specific hook.

Comment: I want to update my state with the hook. I'm not using setState or class components. I was just mentioning is it like setState or not.

Comment: Edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `useState` as said in the following way:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({name: '' })

if (info.name === '') {
  setInfo({...info, name = 'empty'});
}
```

this will set info with only the change of the name property

Answer (score 0):

A hook is something that starts with `use` like `useState`. `setState` is not a hook - it's a setter/updater. It can be used inside of a conditional statement. If it's done properly there shouldn't be any infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

In React Functional Components, useState hook is used as an alternate to state in class components. The correct way to use the useState hook is

```
const [ variable, setVariable ] = React.useState( //default value );
```

The default value can be null, " string ", { object } , true / false, or 0, 1, 2 .......

And just like this.setState() in class components, you set the state with the

```
setVariable( newValue );
```

Never ever try to change the state variables like you change the normal variables. They are immutable for one render and hence cause re-render when called setState.

And for the infinite loop, please copy paste your component